# How to modify value in specific instance of a class without modifying all instances

Tags: python, class, instance

I am somewhat new to Python but not new to programming as a whole and I am trying to build my own Neural Network by myself (no tutorials, libraries or anything like that) and I came into a brick wall:

How to modify a specific instance of a class without modifying all instances.

The problematic code looks like this:

```py
import random

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0.
    def changeValue(self, newValue):
        self.value = newValue


list = [Neuron()] * 8
for i in range(8):
    list[i].changeValue(random.uniform(-1, 1))
    print(list[i].value)

print("Final output:")
for i in range(8):
    print(list[i].value)
```

Which gets me this output in the console:

```
-0.6228121529728226
0.6608409497981214
0.4246020086138289
-0.03140045592115892
-0.9640922324464001
0.9285278812940028
0.10230126874080225
0.4258253680953128
Final output:
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
0.4258253680953128
```

As you can see all the instances become the last changed value (0.4258253680953128) and I honestly have no idea how to fix this.

If there are better alternatives please let me know.
And if there are any questions also let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `list` should not be used as the name for your variable, because it's a built-in name.

The error comes from the initialisation of the list, making it 8 times the same instance of `Neuron`.

Try:

```
list_ = [Neuron() for i in range(8)]
```